# UIImageView EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone

---- MyEventSelectorCell.h

```
@interface MyEventSelectorCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UIImageView*   eventImage;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView*  anImage;
```

----- MyEventSelectorCell.m

```
-(id) dealloc {
    [anImage release];// < -- If I comment this out, It starts leaking, but program runs fine...
}
```

---- MyTableViewController.h

```
@MyTableViewController: UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MyEventSelectorCell* tmpCell;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyEventSelectorCell* tmpCell;
```

---- MyTableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

...

   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyEventSelectorCell" owner:self options:nil];
   tmpCell.anImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"someimage.png"];

...

}
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens after I release anImage when setting the UIImageView .image property to imageNamed above...

Comment: You need to add [super dealloc] to the end of your dealloc. Normally dealloc returns void; you declared to return id but didn't return it. Your compiler is throwing all sorts of warnings that you're ignoring.

Answer (score 3):

[UIImage imagedNamed:...] returns a autorelease object. So, if you release too you have to retain explicitly:

```
tmpCell.anImage.image = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"someimage.png"] retain];
```

Hope that helps you. Cheers.

Comment: There is memory leaking after my solution?

Comment: This is incorrect. The `UIImageView` object keeps a strong reference to the `UIImage` instance, which means that there's no need to explicitly retain the `UIImage` instance.

Answer (score 1):

R31n4ld0 is technically correct, but since UIImageView retains its image, you shouldn't explicitly retain it yourself.

Your issue may be occurring because you're releasing a view thats retained by a property with the "retain" attribute. Synthesized "retain" properties include implicit calls to release and retain in the setter, so the usual pattern in dealloc is to assign them nil instead of calling release on the property itself. This prevents redundant release calls upon reassignment of the property.